# OctoberCMS autocomplete feature integration

Tags: php, octobercms

I have created website using OctoberCMS and here is the demo link of it http://test2.rettest.com/slp_website/

Everthing works fine as of now and the thing is now I want to implement **autocomplete** feature in my website at **Search properties for sale** something like this website has https://www.domain.com.au/ .

If you type **NSW** , **VIC** etc, you will be able to see **autocomplete** box there. I want to implement similar kind of feature in my website at **Search properties for sale**.

As of now, for this section, I have created a **partial** called as **homepage_video_banner.htm** and for this section, I have put below code.

**homepage_video_banner.htm**(Partial)

```
  <form method="post" action="/search/allsale" id="search_form" >
            <p class="property-heading">Search properties for sale</p>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" 
                       aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
                       placeholder="Search Properties by address, state, suburb"  
                       name="q" 
                       id="q"
                       data-request="" 
                       data-request-success="console.log(data)" 
                       data-track-input="true" 
                       autocomplete="off" 
                       value="{{ search_value.q }}"
                       type="text">  

                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2" onclick="$('#search_form').submit()"><i class="fa fa-search visible-xs"></i><span class="hidden-xs searh-btn" >Search</span></span> </div>




</form>
```

This works fine as of now, I can type and able to search my data after redirect and able to see my records which I typed in input box.

Only thing requires is to implement *autocomplete* here.

I have gone through and tried with following links below to implement this feature.

- https://octobercms.com/forum/post/autocomplete-search-form-using-octobercms-ajax-framework
- https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/attributes-api
- https://octobercms.com/forum/post/creating-autocomplete

But these links lacks the response and solution hence I had to ask over here.

Can you guide me an ideal way to accomplish this please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK guys,

I am not sure OctoberCMS does have any dedicated documentation to achieve this, however I found out that it is flexible to use any jquery library of autocomplete to achieve the same thing hence I have used [Selectize](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) library to be able to achieve this.

Hope this helps.